# Question on a derivative on a Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, derivatives, hilbert-spaces, gateaux-derivative

I have this functional  $J(u)=\frac12 \|u\|^2+\int_0^1 F(t,Ku(t))dt$ where $F(t,u)=\int_0^u f(t,\xi) d\xi$,$\displaystyle Ku(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s)u(s) ds$ with $G(t,s)=\begin{cases} s(1-t),&0\leq s \leq t\leq 1\\t(1-s), &0\leq t\leq s \leq 1\end{cases}$

we define the Nemytskii operator $N_f : H\rightarrow H$ where $N_{f}u(t)=f(t,u(t)),\ t\in [0,1]$

and we have  $J'(u)v=(u-KN_fK u,v)$ ,

For $\tau>0$

**I'm trying to prove that $\frac{d}{d\tau} J(\tau u)=(J'(\tau u),u)$**

it's written like that, and it gives the area that we applied the derivative of a composed function!

But whene i used the definition (Gateaux) i found:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \frac{J(\tau u+sh)-J(\tau u)}{s}=(J'(\tau u),h)$$ for all $h\in H$
so $\nabla J(\tau u)=J'(\tau u)$

how to find that $\frac{d}{d\tau}J(\tau u)=(J'(\tau u),u)$ ??

Thank you.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{d\tau}J(\tau u) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{J((\tau+h)u)-J(\tau u)}{h}.$$

Comment: but the definition i have of Gateau is $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+th)-f(a)}{t}$

Comment: I did not write the definition of the Gateaux derivative, but the derivative of the function $t \mapsto J(t u)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $J \colon H \to \mathbb{R}$ is G-differentiable. By definition, given $u \in H$, there is a linear functional $J'(u) \in H^*$, the G-derivative at $u$. By the Riesz representation theorem, this element is isometrically identified to a vector $\nabla J(u) \in H$, called the gradient of $J$ at $u$.
Now, consider thae map
$$
\phi \colon \tau \xrightarrow{\ell}\tau u \xrightarrow{J}J(\tau u),
$$
and apply the chain rule ($\ell'(\tau)=u$ because $\ell$ is linear in $\tau$):
$$
\phi'(\tau) = \langle \nabla J(\tau u), u \rangle,
$$
which you can rewrite as
$$
\frac{d}{d\tau}J(\tau u)=\langle \nabla J(\tau u),u \rangle.
$$

Comment: i dont understand why $<\nabla J(\tau u),u>$

Comment: Chain rule: the gradien of $J$ evaluated at $\tau u$, multiplied by the derivative of $\ell$, namely $u$ (since $\ell$ is linear in $\tau$.

Comment: why we dont write it $J'(\tau u).u$ why we write it as $<.,.>$ ? please

Comment: Just because I prefer this notation for inner products.

Comment: i want to ask you a question,after some calculus they found that $\frac{d}{dt}J(\tau u)|_{\tau=u_0} <0$ so they say: the continuous function $h(\tau)=J(\tau u)$ is strictly decreasing at $\tau=u_0$, what it means strictly decreasing at a point ?

Comment: I don't know and I don't like that. I think that monotonicity is a global definition. They probably mean exactly that the derivative has a strict sign at that point.

Comment: i have a nother question please, if $v_1,...,v_m$ are the critical point of $J$ and $b>max\lbrace J(v_1),...,J(v_m)\rbrace$, then why $J^b=\lbrace x\in H, J(x)\leq b\rbrace$ is a strong deformation retractor of the space $H$? please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13521/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-siminore)